# Why would updating postgresql-client uninstall postgresql?

Tags: linux, debian, postgresql, apt-get

On a Debian 7 server, apt-get was offering me to upgrate the following 2 packages: postgresql-9.1 and postgresql-client-9.1.
Since I didn't want to restart the database server, I decided only to upgrade the client and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade postgresql-client-9.1
```

But this resulted in postgresql-9.1 being removed. I know that postgresql-9.1 depends on postgresql-client-9.1, but why would upgrading postgresql-client remove postgresql?